# SELECT DISTINCT CASE COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm new to SQL, and trying to return a column in a data set that Counts and/or Sums the total of 1 column only when another column meets the criteria

I've got the below in my Select clause, but as I Group the data later in query and don't output the G.[Constituent ID] I cant count that row (and don't want to as it wont group the data the way i want).

Is there a way around this?

(I'm using Microsoft SQL)

```
SELECT 

(Case WHEN G.[Constituent ID] IN ('2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018') THEN  COUNT(DISTINCT G.[Gift Import ID])) AS [COUNT of Gifts Anonymous]
```

---

This is my whole statement

```
SELECT
a.Apl_Appeal_ID AS [Appeal ID],
A.Apl_Description AS [Appeal Description],
A.Apl_Start_date AS [Appeal Start Date],
A.Apl_Campaign_ID AS [Campaign ID],
SUM(A.Apl_No_solicited) AS [Number Solicited],
SUM(A.Apl_ApE_1_01_Amount) AS [Appeal Expenses],
RIGHT(A.Apl_Appeal_ID,1) AS [PackCode],
A.Apl_AtrCat_1_01_Description AS [Gift Classification],
A.Apl_AtrCat_2_01_Description AS [Channel],
A.Apl_AtrCat_3_01_Description AS [MD/Corp],
A.Apl_AtrCat_4_01_Description AS [Purpose],
A.Apl_AtrCat_5_01_Description AS [Campaign],
A.Apl_AtrCat_6_01_Description AS [Wave],
A.Apl_AtrCat_7_01_Description AS [Supplier],
A.Apl_AtrCat_8_01_Description AS [Timing],
A.Apl_AtrCat_9_01_Description AS [Year],
COUNT(DISTINCT G.[Constituent ID]) AS [COUNT of Donors],
COUNT(DISTINCT G.[Gift Import ID]) AS [COUNT of Gifts],
SUM(G.[Gift Amount]) AS [Income],

(Case WHEN G.[Constituent ID] IN ('2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018') THEN  COUNT(DISTINCT G.[Gift Import ID])) AS [COUNT of Gifts Anonymous]



FROM dbo.[FHF_Appeals] A

LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.FHF_Gifts_ExcludingRG G
ON A.Apl_Appeal_ID = G.[Appeal List]

WHERE (a.Apl_Campaign_ID = '1002100-Acquisition' AND A.Apl_AtrCat_2_01_Description LIKE 'Direct_Mail')
    AND A.Apl_Start_date >= '1/1/2014'

GROUP BY 
A.Apl_Appeal_ID, 
A.Apl_Description, 
A.Apl_Start_date, 
A.Apl_Campaign_ID,
A.Apl_AtrCat_1_01_Description,
A.Apl_AtrCat_2_01_Description,
A.Apl_AtrCat_3_01_Description,
A.Apl_AtrCat_4_01_Description,
A.Apl_AtrCat_5_01_Description,
A.Apl_AtrCat_6_01_Description,
A.Apl_AtrCat_7_01_Description,
A.Apl_AtrCat_8_01_Description,
A.Apl_AtrCat_9_01_Description
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the `CASE` expression as an argument to the `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN G.[Constituent ID] IN ('2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018')
               THEN G.[Gift Import ID]
      END) AS [COUNT of Gifts Anonymous]
```